# How do you install the Android SDK in Eclipse Mars?

Tags: 14.04, eclipse, android-sdk

I have installed Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu (14.04 LTS 64-bit), and now want to use the Android SDK on it. How can I achieve this?

Additional information: I have also installed Android Studio, and therefore the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Using Eclipse IDE as a DEV platform for Android used to be "mainstream" in Android development. To do that - you had to install the sdk and add-on.

Android Studio has replaced the Eclipse+SDK configuration as the standard development platform, and it is the development kit itself.

So - no need to use both. If you're new to android, I'd say go with the Android Studio - it's prone to be supported officially from now on.

If you have worked with Eclipse before - you can find more information here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

If you want to work with Eclipse still - you need to download the ADT from the Eclipse store: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/android-development-tools-eclipse, and the usage is similar to previous versions (set the SDK in settins, etc.)

Comment: I am aware that Android Studio has replaced Eclipse as the standard development platform, however a colleague has developed a project on Eclipse, and I want to prevent compatibility issues. In general, I will be working on Android Studio.

Comment: Oh - then I assume you're just asking how to use the ADT with eclipse? well, I edited the answer - does that help?